# shell script to convert .xls to .csv and then delete the .xls files that are converted?

Tags: bash, shell, export-to-csv, xls

I have a simple shell script which runs in a crontab and converts the .xls files into .csv format using libreoffice command. The excel files are generated every 5 minutes, so I want to delete the .xls files once the conversion is done. Below is the code i am using,

```
cat xlscsv.sh

for i in /reports/cctv_xls/*.xls; do libreoffice --headless --convert-to csv "$i" --outdir /cctv_reports/cctv_csv/; done
for i in /reports/cctv_csv/*.csv; do sed -i 1,5d "$i"; done
```

What I have to do is, using the same script, delete the .xls files that got converted to csv. Don't want to run seperate script for deletion. There are 5 .xls files that gets generated every 5 minutes. Please help on achieving this.

Comment: You should add this line at the bottom of your script: rm -f /reports/cctv_xls/*.xls

Comment: Thanks. Will check this too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit this line:

```
for i in /reports/cctv_xls/*.xls; do libreoffice --headless --convert-to csv "$i" --outdir /cctv_reports/cctv_csv/; done
```

to be

```
for i in /reports/cctv_xls/*.xls; do libreoffice --headless --convert-to csv "$i" --outdir /cctv_reports/cctv_csv/ && rm $i; done
```

this will delete the `xls` file only if its successfully converted to `csv`

Comment: sure i will test this and revert. Thanks